# Evaluate a Dice 10,000 roll

Tags: code-golf, game

### Introduction

Dice 10,000 is a dice game which can be played with 6 dice and something to write. Players roll the dice multiple times a turn and gain a score at the end of it. The player who reaches 10,000 point first wins the game. Calculating the score of one roll is your job in this challenge.
[Look here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dice_10000) for the full rules.
*Please note that the rules (especically the scoring) change from region to region since the game is widely known. We use the rules descibed below.*

### The Challenge

Given a list of six numbers from one to six representing a dice roll, output their score. The score is calculated in the follwing way:

- Ones counts **100** points
- Fives counts **50** points
- Triplets count their number **times 100** points. Three twos for example give 200 points. An exception are three ones which count **1000** points.
- Six of the same number count like two triplets as described above. So six threes give 600 points. The same goes for the edge case with the ones: Six ones are 2,000 points.
- One die can't be used more than once. If a die is part of a triplet, it does not count for other scorings. The fives in a triplet do **not** count 50 points in addition to the 500 points they give.
- Triples are always counted first to maximize the score. So three fives are never counted as 150 points. Four fives are counted as one triplet and one ordinary five which then gives 550 points.

#### Notes

- The input will always contain six numbers from one to six. You will not recieve invalid input.
- The numbers can be in any order. You may not assume any specific ordering.

## Rules

- Input format is up to  you as long as it's not preprocessed.
- Function or full program allowed.
- [Default rules](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods) for input/output.
- [Standard loopholes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) apply.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so lowest byte-count wins. Tiebreaker is earlier submission.

## Test cases

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] -> 150
[1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5] -> 1050
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1] -> 2000
[2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2] -> 400
[6, 6, 1, 5, 5, 6] -> 800
[2, 3, 4, 6, 2, 4] -> 0
[1, 5, 1, 5, 1, 5] -> 1500
[5, 5, 5, 5, 2, 3] -> 550
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5] -> 1250
[3, 3, 4, 4, 3, 4] -> 700
```

Comment: Though it has slightly different rules, this made me think of [Zilch](http://www.kongregate.com/games/gaby/zilch).

Comment: Also, *die* is the singular form of *dice*.

Comment: Technically, you can use both, but *die* is preferred.

Comment: @ThreeFx "A dice" is still incorrect. See http://english.stackexchange.com/a/167107/125966

Comment: @mbomb007 See [this](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/dice).

Comment: @mbomb007 In german its the same for singular and plural, why does english has to be so complicated? :P But thanks anyway, *die* sounds actually better :)

Comment: Wow I just noticed that. Funny, actually.

Comment: Is a trailing `.0` on some (but not all) outputs okay? (i.e. `1000.0`)

Comment: @Copper Don't see a reason against it, go ahead!

Comment: @DenkerAffe ah but is it "Der dice", "Die dice" or "Das dice"?

Comment: Can I output nothing instead of 0?

Comment: @DenkerAffe What Dave said. Having 2 words is better than having 3 articles to memorize for every noun.

Comment: @mbomb007 Actually you need only two articels, one for the singular and one for the plural. But anyway, I was joking ofc ;)

Comment: @DenkerAffe From the number of possible articles, though. Der, das, die.

Comment: @mbomb007 There are even more, depending on the case ^^

Comment: @Riley Gonna go with no on that, sorry. Output should always be a number.

Comment: @Dave Or "einen Dice", "dem Dice", "ein Dice", "eine Dice"...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/), <s>34</s> <s>31</s> 30 bytes

```
7G¹N¢O3‰N*2LRN1Q+°*X5‚Nå_i¨}OO
```

**Explanation**

```
7G                                  # for N in 1..6
  ¹N¢O                              # count number of occurrences of N in input
      3‰                            # divmod 3
        N*                          # multiply by N
          2LRN1Q+°*                 # multiply by 10, 100 or 1000
                   X5‚Nå_i¨}        # if N is not 1 or 5, scrap the singles
                            OO      # sum all triple and single scores so far
                                    # implicitly display total sum
```

[Try it online](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=N0fCuU7Cok8z4oCwTioyTFJOMVErwrAqWDXigJpOw6VfacKofU9P&input=WzEsIDEsIDEsIDIsIDMsIDVd)

Answer (score 4):

## Python 2, <s>152</s> <s>148</s> 125 bytes

Pretty simple solution. Can be golfed more. `L.count` is a bit long, but I couldn't remove the first call because L is updated.

```python
def f(L):s=n=0;exec"n+=1\nwhile L.count(n)>2:s+=[n*100,1e3][n<2];exec'L.remove(n);'*3\n"*6;C=L.count;print s+100*C(1)+50*C(5)
```

[**Try it online**](http://ideone.com/5sXQ0L) - (all test cases)

**Ungolfed:**

```python
def f(L,s=0):
    L.sort()
    for n in range(1,7):
        while L.count(n)>2:
            s+=n*100*((n<2)*9+1) # multiply by 10 if n==1
            i=L.index(n)
            L=L[:i]+L[i+3:]
    s+=100*L.count(1)+50*L.count(5)
    print s
```

*Some golf credit to [@Copper](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/56755/copper), using some tips from his code*

Answer (score 4):

### PowerShell <s>v2+</s> v3+, <s>147</s> <s>144</s> <s>137</s> 133 bytes

```
$n=$args[0]|sort;while($n){if(($x=$n[0])-eq$n[2]){$s+=100*$x+900*($x-eq1);$a,$b,$n=$n}else{$s+=50*($x-in1,5)+50*($x-eq1)}$a,$n=$n};$s
```

<sub>*Crossed out 144 looks kinda like 144?*</sub>

Takes input `$args[0]` and `sort`s it, stores it into `$n`. Then, `while` there are still elements left, we evaluate an `if`/`else`.

If the first element (temp stored into `$x` to save some bytes) matches the third element, we have a triple. Add onto the `$s`um the result of some multiplication `100*$x` plus a Boolean-based `900` only if `$x` is `-eq`ual to `1`. This gets us the requisite `1000` for three ones. Then, peel off the first two elements into `$a`, and `$b`, and the remaining into `$n` -- removing the third element of the triple is handled later.

Otherwise, we don't have a triple, so add on to `$s`um the result of another Boolean-based addition. We add `50` if `$x` is either `1` or `5`, then add on another `50` if it's `-eq`ual to `1`. This section now requires v3+ for the `-in` operator.

In either case, we still have an element yet to remove, so peel off the first element into `$a` and leave the remaining in `$n`.

Finally, once the loop is done, place `$s` on the pipeline. Output is an implicit `Write-Output` at the end of execution.

#### Test cases

```
PS C:\Tools\Scripts\golfing> (1,2,3,4,5,6),(1,1,1,2,3,5),(1,1,1,1,1,1),(2,2,2,2,2,2),(6,6,1,5,5,6),(2,3,4,6,2,4),(1,5,1,5,1,5),(5,5,5,5,2,3),(1,1,1,1,1,5),(3,3,4,4,3,4)|%{($_-join',')+" -> "+(.\evaluate-dice-1000.ps1 $_)}
1,2,3,4,5,6 -> 150
1,1,1,2,3,5 -> 1050
1,1,1,1,1,1 -> 2000
2,2,2,2,2,2 -> 400
6,6,1,5,5,6 -> 800
2,3,4,6,2,4 -> 0
1,5,1,5,1,5 -> 1500
5,5,5,5,2,3 -> 550
1,1,1,1,1,5 -> 1250
3,3,4,4,3,4 -> 700
```

Comment: in re: 'crossed out 144': bold your strikethrough, it'll be more obvious.

Answer (score 3):

## Ruby, <s>80</s> 78 bytes

[Try it online!](https://repl.it/CqHQ/3)

-2 byte from @ezrast.

```
->d{s=0;7.times{|i|c=d.count i;i<2&&i=10;s+=c>2?c/3*i*100:1>i%5?c%3*i*10:0};s}
```

Comment: This gives me a SyntaxError. I think you need a space after the first colon.

Comment: @Jordan Even though it worked fine on repl.it it still breaks... it's OK, I rearranged the logic to not require it any more

Comment: `i<2&&i=10` saves you 2 bytes.

Answer (score 3):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>87</s> 86 bytes

```
a=>a.sort().join``.replace(/(.)\1\1|1|5/g,s=>r+=s>>7?s/1.11:s>5?1e3:s>1?50:100,r=0)&&r
```

Sorts and stringifies the input so that scoring combinations can be identified by means of regexp. Edit: Saved 1 byte thanks to @Arnauld.

Comment: `s>>7` instead of `s>111` saves one byte in the first version

Answer (score 3):

## Python 2 or 3, <del>123 122 121 116 109 108 104 102 100</del> 97 bytes

**Python 2, 97 bytes**

```python
lambda r:100*sum(c/3*((v<2)*9+v)+c%3*(v<2or(v==5)/2.)for v,c in enumerate(map(r.count,range(7))))
```

Test cases are on [**ideone**](http://ideone.com/4guQTz)

**Python 3, 97 bytes**

```python
lambda r:100*sum(c//3*((v<2)*9+v)+c%3*(v<2or(v==5)/2)for v,c in enumerate(map(r.count,range(7))))
```

Answer (score 2):

### Haskell, <s>130</s> 123 bytes

This is *not* a challenge for Haskell. Also I am in golfing this.

Thanks to @nimi.

```
import Data.List
f=g.sort
g(x:a@(y:z:b))|x>z=j x+g a|0<1=100*h x+g b
g(x:y)=j x+g a
g _=0
h 1=10
h x=x
j 1=100
j 5=50
j _=0
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3, 131 bytes

```py
lambda r,C=list.count:sum([x%7*100,1e3][x%7<2]*(C(r,x%7)>2and not exec('r.remove(x%7);'*3))for x in range(14))+50*C(r,5)+100*C(r,1)
```

This is a lambda expression; to use it, assign it by prepending `f=`.

We first check for triples twice (by using modulus), removing the triples as we go; then we simply add the counts of `5` and `1` to the score and return it.

[Try it on Ideone!](http://ideone.com/FLjD1h) (with all test cases)

Here's my older Python 2 submission:

### Python 2, <s>176</s> <s>172</s> <s>171</s> <s>145</s> <s>136</s> <s>134</s> 133 bytes

```py
def e(r):s=x=0;exec'x+=1;a=x%7;\nif r.count(a)>2:exec"r.remove(a);"*3;s+=[a*100,1e3][a<2]\n'*14;C=r.count;s+=50*C(5)+100*C(1);print s
```

*Saved a byte on the Python 2 solution thanks to @mbomb007!*

Comment: `print s` is shorter in Python 2.

Comment: @mbomb007 Thanks! I'll edit that in.

Answer (score 1):

## BASH (sed + bc) 161

```
sed -re's/([1-6])(.*)\1(.*)\1/\100\2\3/g;s/([1-6])( .*)\1( .*)\1/\100\2\3/g;s/10/1/g; s/1/100/g;s/5( |$)/50 /g;s/[1-6][^0]//g;s/ +/+/g;s/(^\+|\+$)//g;s/^$/0/'|bc
```

I wanted to do it all in sed, but addition is really hard...

Explanation:

1. Find a triplet, add `00` to the first number and remove the other
   e.g. `1 2 1 3 1 4` -> `100 2 3 4`
2. Repeat step 1 incase there are two triples
3. Replace `10` with `1` then `1` with `100`
   e.g. `100` -> `10` -> `1000` or `1` -> `1` -> `100`
4. Replace each `5` not followed by `0` with `50`
5. Remove any number that doesn't end in `0`
6. Replace groups of spaces with `+`
7. Remove leading and trailing `+`s
8. If the string is empty, add a `0`
9. Lastly pipe to `bc` to add everything up.

Answer (score 1):

### Javascript (ES6), <s>85</s> 84 bytes

```
x=>x.map(v=>s+=v*(((z+=1<<v*3)>>v*3&7)%3?v-5?v-1?0:10:1:v-5?v-1?10:80:8),s=z=0)|10*s
```

Test cases:

```js
let F =
x=>x.map(v=>s+=v*(((z+=1<<v*3)>>v*3&7)%3?v-5?v-1?0:10:1:v-5?v-1?10:80:8),s=z=0)|10*s

console.log(F([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])); // 150
console.log(F([1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5])); // 1050
console.log(F([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])); // 2000
console.log(F([2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2])); // 400
console.log(F([6, 6, 1, 5, 5, 6])); // 800
console.log(F([2, 3, 4, 6, 2, 4])); // 0
console.log(F([1, 5, 1, 5, 1, 5])); // 1500
console.log(F([5, 5, 5, 5, 2, 3])); // 550
console.log(F([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5])); // 1250
console.log(F([3, 3, 4, 4, 3, 4])); // 700
```

Answer (score 1):

## Perl, 69 bytes

Includes +2 for `-ap`

Run with the input on STDIN:

```
dice10000.pl <<< "5 1 1 1 1 1"
```

`dice10000.pl`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -ap
$_=join 0,sort@F,A;print;s%(10|\d)\1\1|10|5%$n+=$1.0||$&%eg;$_=$n.0
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for an input like "2 2 2 2 2 2"

Answer (score 0):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), <s>228</s> 227 bytes

```cs
class A{static void Main(string[] a){int[] x=new int[7];int i=0,s=0;for(;i<6;i++)x[int.Parse(a[i])]++;while(i>0){while(x[i]>2){s+=i>1?10*i:100;x[i]-=3;}i--;}while(x[1]-->0)s+=10;while(x[5]-->0)s+=5;System.Console.Write(s*10);}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYtBS8QwEIX/So7JxpREqYKzqYhnQfDgoeQQulEHuglkgrtS@ttjqqy8w3x8781Eako51DrNnog9LlR8wYl9JTywZ4@RU8kYP0bHvFgwlgZnG8OJbXznoB2GVl@R1fCeMgfc3wJKKc5jq7oXnylwP6ITTko4feIcOA5aLH/YVm64FgtJi4N5MHqH90Zr2LyyN7CiUrBetsYp1X7b2Gi4yP5f9vD6TSUcu6cUKc2he8tYAqed0QLWtdba/8Zs@QE)

I feel like I'm missing many, many potential optimizations here, but I *did* save a byte by multiplying by 10 at the end.  Input should be passed as separate command line args.

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-ap`, 78 bytes

```perl
$_=join'',sort@F;s|(\d)\1\1|!($\+=$1*($1-1?2:20))|ge;$\+=y/5//+2*y/1//}{$\*=50
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcixCsIwEADQX4kQaJIaLxfIYgl1cvMPDkSwSEWa0HQppr/uSZc3vDzMn8As7/GdxqlpjiXNy@XalaroqQkJ60FJaqNEoyRa7P3ZO63ra@j2XiEAtN6sgADbV5KJwTGjQOHFbvilvIxpKmxv4eTQsX3kPw)